# Qt viewport size is wrong

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I want to place an image in my Qt GUI. The issue that I have is with the scaling of the image after it has been loaded - it appears to be scaled down. That occurs due to an error in `fitInView()` routine that gets called to fit the image to the given window size. In particular, in my *re-implementation* of `fitInView()` there is the following line:

```
viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
```

`viewport().rect()` returns incorrect results because the image has not been shown yet, and that causes the Widget to have "bogus sizes", as has been pointed out in [this forum thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/62233-Understanding-GraphicsView-Viewport-Size).

Possible solutions that I found mostly agree with each other on one thing - one has to implement a `showEvent()` routine that would call `fitInView()`; that way, the image would have time to properly load and the Widget viewport will be set to a correct value. I tried that:

```
def showEvent(self, event):
    self.fitInView()
```

That function is invoked after I choose an image that I want to upload, and call `self.show()` to show that image. However, implementing `showEvent()` did not solve the problem. Has anyone come across this issue before?

Answer (score -1):

The solution turned out to be very similar to what I tried. Simply setting and fitting the pixmap *after* calling `window.show()` has fixed the size problem! It is also necessary to keep the `showEvent()` routine for this to work correctly.